# cordova pushplugin can't get device token in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I'm trying to add push notifications on cordova/phonegap apps using the pushplugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

I installed the plugin with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

It seems it's working because when I run the app for the first time on my device (iPhone 5) it says "your app want send you notifications bla bla..." but then I don't get the device token: it should show an alert by now.

This is how I edited the default index.js created by cordova:

```js
var pushNotification;
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        // app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  
  
  
   // var pushNotification;
  
  
  
  $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');
                
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
    {
                 $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');
       
          if( $("#home").length > 0)
     {
      // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
      //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
      e.preventDefault();
      navigator.app.exitApp();
     }
     else
     {
      navigator.app.backHistory();
     }
    }, false);
   
    try 
    { 
                 pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
                 if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                            device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
   pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"661780372179","ecb":"onNotification"});  // required!
     } else {
                     pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"}); // required!
                 }
                }
    catch(err) 
    { 
     txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
     txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
     alert(txt); 
    }
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  







// handle APNS notifications for iOS
            function onNotificationAPN(e) {
                if (e.alert) {
                     $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                     // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
                     navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
                }
                    
                if (e.sound) {
                    // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                    snd.play();
                }
                
                if (e.badge) {
                    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
                }
            }
            
            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            function onNotification(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');
                
                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
     if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
     {
      $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
      // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
      // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
      console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
     }
                    break;
                    
                    case 'message':
                     // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                     // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                     if (e.foreground)
                     {
       $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            
              // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                     // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                     var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                     // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                     // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                     var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

       my_media.play();
      }
      else
      { // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
       if (e.coldstart)
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
       else
       $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
      }
       
      $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                        //android only
      $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                        //amazon-fireos only
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                    break;
                    
                    case 'error':
      $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;
                    
                    default:
      $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    alert(result);
            }
   
            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }
            
            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }
            
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

In the index.html I didn't make any change... just added the last two .js files like in the example even if the index.html is almost empty

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // var pushNotification;
   
   
   
   
   
 </script>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not even sure I added the var pushNotification and all the functions in the right places... 
I'm very new to phonegap, trying to learn but all the examples I find are very different from the files created when I make a new app.

I also read there are some problems with pushplugin and iOS 8, can't understand if they've been solved or not.
Anyone can give me any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index.js` is all fine, you need to fix following things in your `index.html`:

1: You dont have to inlcude  `PushNotifications.js` on your own, so remove
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>`, 
`cordova.js` will include automatically all plugins js files.

2: Include script `jquery` above `index.js`.

3: In you index.js you have following code

```
if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                            device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
```

This will give you error because `device` object is not defined, actually it is object which is exported from device plugin,so install this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) by runnig command 
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

4: Also add `<ul id="app-status-ul"></ul>` in your index.html, so you can see results. 
Make these changes and your code will work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Yes I had already added device plugin, forgot to say.
Removed PushNotification.js in index.html.

My big mistake I forgot to put an alert in the errorHandler function. Once I did it I noticed it was a problem with the provisioning profile: Xcode loaded the generic one instead that the AdHoc with my certificate.

Changed now it's showing the device token.

Comment: Noticed that Xcode alerts for lots of deprecated objects in pushplugin.m for iOS 8 and iOS 7 builds. For this I think I will have to update the file like I saw in some posts here.
And when i run the app on my iphone it runs correctly but on Xcode I get this message "process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch" and stops the run even if on the device the app is still running.
If you got any idea for these problems too I accept suggestions.

Comment: Not sure but try `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-push-notification` instead of installing  from git url. For android it fixes build issues, dont know about ios. But you can give a try.